# Msaccess , save as pdf cambiar nombre de archivo en Dialog box de save as

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

Salvando un reporte en PDF con un botón, quisiera poder cambiar dinámicamente el nombre del archivo "reportehotel.pdf" a "Hoteles-2022.pdf" en el `Dialog Box`. Algo simple, sin que se guarde automáticamente en el output, ¿Qué debo agregar?

```
 Private Sub Command148_Click()
 On Error GoTo Command148_Click_Err

 Dim stDocName As String
 Dim alchivo As String

 stDocName = "reportehotel"

 DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, , True


Command148_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

Command148_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error
Resume Command148_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que el archivo siempre se llame `Hoteles-2022.pdf` simplemente cambia `stDocName = "reportehotel"` por `stDocName = "Hoteles-2022"`

Si lo que quieres es que cada vez que vayas a generad el PDF te pregunte un nombre, podrías añadir un Inputbox que te lo pida. En vez de `stDocName = "reportehotel"` pon `stDocName = Inputbox("Escriba nombre")`